# Why is selenium web driver doesn't find the textfield on this website?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

What should happen is that these textfields for login should be filled and the the login button should be pressed (some sort of auto login)

Here is the link to the webpage: [Telekom Email Login Page](https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup)

#### This are the three methods I'm using:

```
public String exportDriver() throws IOException {
        final InputStream IEDriverStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Driver/IEDriverServer.exe");
        final File ieDriverServer = FileWebOpener.stream2file(IEDriverStream, "IEDriverServer", ".exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieDriverServer.getAbsolutePath());
        return ieDriverServer.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public void goToWebsite(String url) {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public void setUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password, int Website) throws InterruptedException {
       try{ new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#user[name='pw_usr']"))).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#pw_pwd[name='pw_pwd']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.standard_button_size.large#pw_submit")).click();
    } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

[This is the exception I get](https://pastebin.com/LdjEXtFH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with C# and get the right behaviors.
Below is the code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace IEWebDriver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : "test";
            string password = args.Length > 1 ? args[2] : "test";
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            //Navigate to test URL
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup");

            try
            {
                new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20, 60)).Until(c => c.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#user[name='pw_usr']"))).SendKeys(username);
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#pw_pwd[name='pw_pwd']")).SendKeys(password);
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.button.standard_button_size.large#pw_submit")).Click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            //Close the browser
            driver.Quit();
            //driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True had something todo with the Driverr Installation I had with another driver it worked

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first need to :

1. click on the username field.
2. send username keys.
3. click on the password field.
4. send password keys.
5. click on the submit button

try- findElement(By.Class("line_normalized clear relative").click);

this find the username textfield class and clicks on it if Im not mistaken, syntax may be wrong but the idea is the same.
same goes for the password field, find the class/id name of the field & click on it before sending keys.

Comment: I tried it like that: `WebElement line_normalized_clear_relative = driver.findElement(By.class("line_normalized clear relative"));
        line_normalized_clear_relative.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(username);` I got this error message: _Unable to find element with css selector == .line_normalized\ clear\ relative
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html_

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to input the login info into the fields and click on login, if so:

WebElement line_normalized_clear_relative = driver.findElement(By.class("line_normalized clear relative").click());   to find the username field & click on it , then 

 line_normalized_clear_relative.sendKeys ("the username");
then repeat with password & eventually click on submit

Comment: Now I tried like you said: `WebElement line_normalized_clear_relative = driver.findElement(By.className("line_normalized clear relative"));
        line_normalized_clear_relative.click();
        line_normalized_clear_relative.sendKeys(username);` Got the same error message as before I didn't get the element (textfield) and so everything else fails too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as you want to enter the username and it's a input field, you need to locate the input tag.

you can try the following locator to locate the text input area and perform the sendkeys operation:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='line_normalized clear relative']/input")).sendKeys("username");
```

Comment: Did you mean something like that (to autofill username field):  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='line_normalized clear relative']/input")).sendKeys(username);`

Comment: yeah, you just need to use the locator which i mentioned above, to locate the username text field, and then you can perform the sendkeys operation, it's working for me.

Comment: And the input is the tag of the textfield?

Comment: exactly! you just use the locator i have mentioned and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your application is too slow.Use `WebDriverWait` to identify the element and then `Sendkeys` operation.

```
package pkg1;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class testIE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "\\Executables\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        
        driver.get("https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement user= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("user")));
        user.sendKeys("user12345@gmail.com");
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement pass= wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("pw_pwd")));
        pass.sendKeys("password");


    }

}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: This isn't working too. I get a huge repeating errorstack

Comment: Did you provided your webdriver path?

Comment: Yeah I put it in jar as ressource and read the inputstream in a temp file. Then I seit itˋs path as the webdriver property

Comment: And the get Method works perfectly, which isn't possible without the IEDriver

Answer (score 0):

As you are accessing the [website](https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup) initially you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#user[name='pw_usr']"))).sendKeys("Jannik");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#pw_pwd[name='pw_pwd']")).sendKeys("Jannik");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.standard_button_size.large#pw_submit")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://accounts.login.idm.telekom.com/idmip?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Fverify%3FreturnToUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Femail.t-online.de%2Fem&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de&openid.assoc_handle=S4d53c348-b3f2-49a9-b13e-65ade0af6da4&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_request&openid.ext1.type.attr1=urn%3Atelekom.com%3Aall&openid.ext1.required=attr1&openid.ns.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Foauth2%2F1.0&openid.ext2.client_id=10LIVESAM30000004901PORTAL00000000000000&openid.ext2.scopes=W3sic2NvcGUiOiJzcGljYSJ9XQ%3D%3D&openid.ns.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Fidm.telekom.com%2Fopenid%2Fext%2F2.0&openid.ext3.logout_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Ftipi.api.t-online.de%2Fsrp-auth%2FoneIdm%2Flogout&openid.ns.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.ext4.mode=popup");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='user' and @name='pw_usr']"))).sendKeys("Jannik");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pw_pwd' and @name='pw_pwd']")).sendKeys("Jannik");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button standard_button_size large' and @id='pw_submit']")).click();
  ```

Comment: I tried the cssSelector method and get this error: `Element info: {Using=css selector, value=input#user[name='pw_usr']}
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)`

Comment: Can you please update the main question with your current code trial and the error stack trace?

Comment: Your code looks good enough **but** as you are using **java.version: '1.8.0_201'** can you upgrade to recent GA version of _Selenium_ ... Possibly _Selenium v3.141.59_ please?

Comment: Ok I will do this

Comment: Have done and now I get a new Exception what I have replaced in the previous link

Comment: Though you are using _Selenium_ of  `version: '3.141.59'` the _InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)_ version is still `3.14.0.0`. Can you take the _IEDriverServer_ **v3.141.59** please?

Comment: I can't find the old versions of them.

Comment: I tried the path variation and now I get an error because the code waits that the element is clickable but it isn't and I guess there is a time period and after that it (selenium WebDriver) abort the process